# ORACLE SQL display duplicates after distinct function call

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query in Oracle Developer that is going to pull specific data from multiple tables and join it into one table with results.

Please find sample code below:

```
select distinct tbl1.Product_ID, tbl2.Supplier_ID
from tbl3
inner join tbl1
on tbl1.Product_ID = tbl3.Product_ID
inner join tbl2
on tbl3.PO_ID = tbl2.PO_ID
where tbl1.Season_ID LIKE 'AA18'
order by tbl1.Product_ID
```

The result is as expected:

```
+------------------+---------------+
|    Product ID    |  Supplier_ID  |
+------------------+---------------+
| ID-1             | NHII88        |
| ID-2             | NHII88        |
| ID-3             | NHII88        |
| ID-4             | NHII88        |
| ID-5             | NHII88        |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Explanation: Distinct is required at this point as without this call multiple Product_ID's (ie ID-1) will be diplayed due to multiple PO's.

Result I am trying to achieve is as per below:

```
+------------------+---------------+
|    Product ID    |  Supplier_ID  |
+------------------+---------------+
| ID-1             | NHII88        |
| ID-1             | LLLLPP        |
+------------------+---------------+

+------------------+---------------+
|    Product ID    |  Supplier_ID  |
+------------------+---------------+
| ID-4             | NHII88        |
| ID-4             | LLLLP         |
| ID-4             | KKKOOP        |
+------------------+---------------+
```

It doesn't exactly need to be grouped in this way, but the idea is to display only duplicate records within this query. 
I have been trying to use HAVING, but I must have done something wrong as this has returned same result as per example one.

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Data example:
Tbl1

```
+------------------+---------------+
|    Product ID    |  Season_ID    |
+------------------+---------------+
| ID-4             | AA18          |
| ID-4             | AA17          |
| ID-4             | AA16          |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Tbl2

```
+------------------+---------------+
|    PO_number     |  Supplier_ID  |
+------------------+---------------+
| PO1234           | NHII88        |
| PO1235           | LLLLPP        |
| PO1236           | KKKOOP        |
+------------------+---------------+
```

Tbl3

```
+------------------+---------------+
|    PO_number     |  Product_ID   |
+------------------+---------------+
| PO1234           | ID-1          |
| PO1235           | ID-2          |
| PO1236           | ID-3          |
+------------------+---------------+
```

My business rules are this.

`tbl1` contains all details about products, such as Product_ID and Season_ID (ID-1 and AA18). `tbl2` contains PO header details such as PO number and Supplier_ID. `tbl3` contains Purchase Order Line details such as PO number and Product_ID.

The idea is to pull all PO numbers from `tbl3` where Product_ID in that table = Product_Id in `tbl1` and Season_ID = AA18. Other Products should be ignored. If result match PO number detail from `tbl3` should be referenced into `tbl2` where Supplier_ID can be found.

Expecting results as mentioned above.

Comment: your question is not clear .. just show your table schema  .. a clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: @ScaisEdge 
in High level:
tbl1 contain all details about products. Such as Product_ID and Season_ID
(ID-1 and AA18)
tbl2 contain PO header details such as PO number and Supplier_ID
tbl3 contain Purchase Order Line details such as PO number and Product_ID

The idea is to pull all PO numbers from tbl3 where Product_ID in that table = Product_Id in tbl1 and Season_ID = AA18. Other Products should be ignored. 
If result match PO number detail from tbl3 should be referenced into tbl2 where Supplier_ID can be found. 

I will add example to question soon.

Comment: @APC
as mentioned above:"I will add example to question soon." 
data sample added to the question.

Comment: Looking to your data you have not relation between  tbl1 and the others tables ...you have not column (or values)  corresponding ..  sees that there are some parts missing ..

Comment: There is a `po_id` column in your first query but in the sample data there is only `po_number`. Are those the same thing? Then TBL1 only has product `ID-4`  which doesn't exist in TBL3, so unless I am missing some twist of your business logic, nothing will join anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The posted sample data doesn't contain any duplicates so it's a bit difficult to see why your required output looks the way it does. However, this implements your posted business rules:

```
select tbl1.Product_ID
       , tbl2.Supplier_ID 
from tbl1
     inner join tbl3 on tbl1.Product_ID = tbl3.Product_ID 
     inner join tbl2 on tbl3.PO_number  = tbl2.PO_number 
where tbl1.Season_ID  = 'AA18'
```

Comment: this is just a small example of data tables. In real world each table contain about 100 columns and 350K records. Data Base is massive and I need to utilize data and be able to efficiently find records. 
I will try your solution first thing in the morning and will keep you updated.
Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Don't know about massive (350k records is trivial) but 100 columns per table certainly sounds like a janky data model. When you do keep us updated please do it by **editing your question** and remember to make your test case as accurate as possible. The answers you get will only be as good as the information you post.